# JSON.parse works in console, but not when running script

Tags: javascript

So here's my text:

```
handleMyKeys(res) {
    // console.log(res);
    console.log("text" + this.responseText); //line 12
    let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log("Output is" + json.keys); //line 14
    console.log(window.mykeys);
    if (json.keys) {
      window.mykeys.setState({keys: json.keys});
    }

  }
```

And it prints out undefined for json.keys.

However when I run the same operation in console, I get a valid JSON object with .keys property. Why?

```
"{\"keys\":[\"itchio\",\"quantumitch\"]}"  MyKeys.js:12
Output isundefined  MyKeys.js:14
Object { props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, _reactInternalFiber: Object, _reactInternalInstance: Object, state: Object }  MyKeys.js:15
x = "{\"keys\":[\"itchio\",\"quantumitch\"]}";
"{"keys":["itchio","quantumitch"]}"
JSON.parse("{\"keys\":[\"itchio\",\"quantumitch\"]}");
Object { keys: Array[2] }
y = JSON.parse("{\"keys\":[\"itchio\",\"quantumitch\"]}")
Object { keys: Array[2] }
y.keys
Array [ "itchio", "quantumitch" ]
```

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here, but you're missing the word `function` in your function declaration. And it looks like you're working with a response called `res` but you're working with something called `this.responseText` in your function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your console output, it looks like your input has been encoded twice.

Compare the console output of the following two statements:

```js
console.log("{\"keys\":[\"itchio\",\"quantumitch\"]}");
console.log("\"{\\\"keys\\\":[\\\"itchio\\\",\\\"quantumitch\\\"]}\"");
```

The output of the second command corresponds to what you're seeing in the console, indicating that the string that you're processing was escaped twice.

Check the content of the response you're receiving, or do a `typeof JSON.parse(this.responseText)` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to write `res` or `res.responseText` instead of `this.responseText`. (depends on what `res` is.)